# Homepage logged as 200 in IIS logs

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, iis

Looking at the IIS logs I am seeing status code 200 for pages that are redirected.

**e.g.**

> the landing page on a site redirects to /pages/default.aspx

So we have an entry for / and an entry for /pages/default.aspx in the logs with a 200. We then analyze the logs and its 2 page views

Why is this?